Control Image Sequence Playback Speed with Geometry nodes
I have a plane with an animation that I am spawning and controlling several aspects of with a geo node setup.
I would like to have controls within the geometry nodes to change the playback speed of the animation on the plane. Is there any way to do this?

The frame number is controlled by the Offset Value of an Image Texture node.
Since Drivers can more easily push or pull a value like this we can try to use them.  Drivers can use the position of an object like an empty very easily, so this may be the way to go- control the position of the empty with geometry nodes and use this to drive the Offset Value of the texture.
The empty's position will be like a playhead for the footage as it moves along the X-axis.
To try this start with a single vert object with a geometry nodes modifier, your image plane with video added, and an empty.
Parent the empty to the vertex, and then use that to drive the offset.
Let's examine the 3 objects required:
The GN object:

The Plane with the Image Texture:

Lastly the empty, has nothing special about it except it is parented to a vertex in the node object.
Then you are free to do whatever calculations you want, Divide or multiply to speed up or slow down the frame rate of that movie plane.
Quellenform has discussed this method here, although the question did not explicitly reference  playback speed.

Use Values in the Group Input
This is another approach which uses less objects- you can link a value to the Group Input node and use it in the driver.

Hover over the created field in the GN modifier, right click and choose Copy Data Path

Go to your Shader Editor and right click or CTRL+d on the Offset field in your material to Add a Driver.
the settings can be:
expression:  var + 0 (whatever your variable name is)
var: choose Single Property** (You can have new var name)
Object: MoviePlane (whatever your object name is)
Path: modifiers["GeometryNodes"]["Socket_2"] ( whatever your copied Path is)
After completing these steps, you should already have control over the timeline of your image sequence, which you can easily set keys for.

Optionally, another variable can be added to the Driver expression.  It could be another value or your current frame. The data path of the current frame is 'frame_current', so you can use it as a variable to perform various calculations as well.

